# My special wpf visual inheritance needs

Tags: wpf, inheritance

I know there are lots of questions here on wpf visual inheritance but I cannot find one which is very close to what I need.
In a CRUD application I have many views (actually they are user controls) which have most components in common. I have a multiple rows and multiple columns grid filled with labels, textbox and other controls. Lets focus, for example, on the cell at row 2 and col 2. Depending on the CRUD operation the user is performing it alternatively contains a label, a textbox, a combobox or it is empty. I learnt form other answers on this site how to make a textbox readonly for the read operation using styles and triggers, but in my case I have to change the control type. Surely I can overlap all the controls I need and change their visibility but I don't think this is the best approach. 
To put it with different words I have some views which share most cells of the grid used for layout but they differ for some components inside specific and limited cells.
What would you do in this case ? In win Forms I could put the common parts inside a base class and derive from it, with xaml I cannot do it.

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, from your comments I gather that you want each context to have its own XAML file, but for it to refer to some common template. Well you could to that as follows:

Set up the common template, for example in CommonControl.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Yellow" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Text="This is some fixed text"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <CheckBox>My first checkbox</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox>My second checkbox</CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=SpecificPart1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Blue"/>
</Grid>
```

This has various UI elements forming a common UI in all Grid positions, except for Grid Row 1, Column 1 (the lower centre pane), where the context specific UI will be shown.

Now in the code behind, CommonControl.xaml.cs, you set up a dependency object to allow the context specific UI to be fed into the template:

```
    public object SpecificPart1
    {
    get { return this.GetValue(SpecificPart1Property); }
    set { this.SetValue(SpecificPart1Property, value); } 
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SpecificPart1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SpecificPart1", typeof(object), typeof(CommonControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

If there is more than one position in which you wish to place context specific UI then you could add another dependency property here for the other part.

Then you can set up as many other XAML files as you like, which all refer to this and insert their own piece of UI to go in the part that varies. Here is one example, which puts some green italic text there. In MySpecificControl.xaml:

```
    <my:CommonControl>
        <my:CommonControl.SpecificPart1>
            <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGreen" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="14">This is my context specific UI</TextBlock>
        </my:CommonControl.SpecificPart1>
    </my:CommonControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a ContentControl with triggers. I don't know exactly what determines which type of control you wish to display, but say for example you have a property "Condition" which can take values "ConditionValue1" or "ConditionValue2" and you wish to show a different piece of UI dependent on which value it is, you could use XAML like this:

```
   <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="ConditionValue1">
                        <Setter Property="ContentControl.Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    [ First control goes here ]
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="ConditionValue2">
                        <Setter Property="ContentControl.Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    [ Second control goes here ]
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

The big advantage of this over using Visibility is that the controls are only loaded when they are needed, and when a different one is put in place, the old one is free to be unloaded. With Visibility=Collapsed, the control is still loaded and hangs around in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd definitely look into [`DataTemplate`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx).

If requirements are simple enough to just select a template based upon the DataType, then you're all set... For example, here is some XAML that will automatically use the correct template (TextBox or DatePicker) if you had a collection of objects that was a mix of `string` and `DateTime`.

```
<MyControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{sys:String}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding}" />
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{sys:DateTime}">
    <DatePicker Date="{Binding}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</MyControl.Resources>

<ItemsControl Items="{Binding MyListOfObjects}" />
```

---

If you need additional logic outside of simply the type, then you will want to look into a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx). For example, if you have a collection of complex objects and some properties within those complex objects that will determine which `DataTemplate` to select, then you should use a `DataTemplateSelector`.

```
<MyControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TextViewTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="Name:" />
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="TextUpdateTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="Name:" />
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>

  <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MySelector"
     ManagerTemplate="{StaticResource TextUpdateTemplate}"
     EmployeeTemplate="{StaticResource TextViewTemplate}" />
</MyControl.Resources>

<ItemsControl Items="{Binding Employees}"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MySelector}" />


public MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ManagerTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EmployeeTempalte { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,
        DependencyObject container)
    {
         switch (UserClass.UserLevel)
         {
            case UserLevel.Manager:
                if (ManagerTemplate != null)
                    return ManagerTemplate;
                break;

            case UserLevel.Employee:
                if (EmployeeTemplate != null)
                    return EmployeeTemplate;
                break;

            default:
                throw InvalidOperationException("Invalid enumeration value.");
         }

         return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

---

Keep in mind that this is just one way of doing this... `DataTemplateSelector`s are very rarely used because a lot of the selection logic can simply be applied to similar templates and exposing an additional property. For example, instead of using this selector you can simply expose a "IsEditable" property and bind it to the IsReadOnly DependencyProperty. But, this was just an example to show the usage. Anyways, hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your solution well. Where are the common controls in it ? What I'm looking for is a way to write all controls used by all my views somewhere (perhaps in a template) and then having multiple views for each use case where I specify only what I want to add respect the basic template. Is there an easy way to achieve this goal ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Can you be more clear with it? Because as it stands right now you're confusion to my answer is my confusion to your comment.

Comment: In a MVVM scenario I have and want to have a view for reading, one for editing, one for create, another for a create special case, ecc. All these views share most part of their components with minor differences: where can I put the common parts ? I don't want a unique xaml file which adapts to the CRUD operation, I would like more xaml file which somehow 'inherit' the common components from another xaml file. May be templating is the right answer but I would need some example to follow.